# detecting rectangle contours not accurate in UML diagrams, openCV

Tags: opencv

I want to extract some rectangles at the top from a UML sequence diagram in jpg format by using OpenCV.

The algorithm I use finds way too many rectangles that are super small and not needed.

I think the mess up is somewhere in the beginning of the code where I apply canny edge detection but I am not sure.

I want to capture only the big rectangles from the top and center.

Thanks for any help.

[image: original diagram]
[image: After running code]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

image = cv2.imread("./diagrams/sd2.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 90, 150, 3)
cnts = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)


def detect(c):
    shape = "unidentified"
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ar = w / float(h)

        shape = "square" if ar >= 0.95 and ar <= 1.05 else "rectangle"

    return shape


# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]))
        cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        shape = detect(c)

        c = c.astype("float")
        c = c.astype("int")

        if(shape == "rectangle"):
            cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cv2.putText(image, shape, (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: If you only want large rectangles, then in your "loop over the contours", you should perhaps skip any of them that are too small? You already know their dimensions, so that's like a single `if` statement.

Comment: I dont want to capture the smaller ones in the first place

Comment: Well, `findContours` is likely to give you some false positives anyway (you already get things that aren't rectangles and filter those out), so it would make sense to do it anyway... but it's your choice, so I won't argue any further.

Comment: It's not that the algorithm is not accurate. It is supposed to detect those dotted lines as rectangles because ***they are in fact rectangles***.  As your detection works fine all you need to do is to filter for big rectangles, as @DanMašek already suggested.